# How are neurotransmitter receptors discovered?

Tags: neuroscience

Many neurotransmitter receptors are known, for example 5-HT<sub>2a</sub>, Mu, NMDA, and so on. How have these receptors been discovered?

Comment: Now? Or originally?

Answer (score 2):

Each receptor has its own story of discovery. I'll share here the methods used by [Lefkowitz](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/chemistry/2012/lefkowitz/facts/) that led to the discovery of one of the first neurotransmitter receptors, namely the [β2 adrenergic receptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrenergic_receptor) (β2AR) from frog erythrocytes in 1981. With this I mean β2AR was among the first receptors that was identified, purified, and characterized both at the protein and DNA level.

Lefkowitz's team was the first to uncover the charactistics of a neurotransmitter  at the protein and DNA level. βARs are involved in regulating cardiovascular function. Lefkowitz was awarded the [Noble prize](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/chemistry/2012/lefkowitz/facts/) for his early pioneering work on the discovery of these receptors.

His method was based on several steps, namely:

- The development of a novel and specific [radioligand binding assay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand_binding_assay) to enable the measurement βAR-binding sites;
- The identification of detergents to successfully solubilize a functional βAR from membrane preparations;
- The synthesis of an affinity resin and photoaffinity ligands to facilitate receptor purification;
- Reconstitution of the purified β2AR into phospholipid vesicles;
- The demonstration that β2AR couples to, and activates the heterotrimeric G protein Gs and subsequent activation of adenylyl cyclase to produce cAMP;
- Purified hamster β2AR was used for peptide sequencing that were subsequently used to synthesize oligonucleotides for cloning studies to isolate β2AR cDNA;

After β1AR, Lefkowitz's lab soon purified β1AR, α1AR, and α2AR.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Benovic, *Cell* (2012); **151**(6): 1148-50](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867412013621)

**-** [Lopez-Munoz & Alamo, *Neural Transm* (2009) **116**: 515–33](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/24261196_Historical_evolution_of_the_neurotransmission_concept)</sub>

Comment: It looks like nAChR was earlier by a couple years, compare https://neurotree.org/beta/publications.php?pid=8115 to references in https://www.mdpi.com/2218-273X/10/4/547 β2AR seems to be the first G-protein coupled receptor, though.